# material ui table pagination alignment

Tags: css, material-ui

[material ui table pagination alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiKxu.png)

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
 <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="cart table">
  <TableHead>
                ...
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
                    ...
  </TableBody>
 </Table>
</TableContainer>
<TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15]}
            component="div"
            count={noPage}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={handleChangePage}
            onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

I can't alignment this material ui table pagination. Please help me!

Comment: it would be better if you replicate the issue on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have sent a picture of my problem above, please check and help me